# resizeEvent срабатывает только один раз

Tags: c++, qt, resizeevent

В моем классе, унаследованном от QWidget, я переопределил resizeEvent, но этот метод срабатывает только один раз, а когда я меняю размеры окна он не срабатывает.

```
class Buttons : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Buttons(QWidget *parent);

private slots:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e) override;
};

void Buttons::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e)
{
    ...
}
```

с другим моим классом я решил проблему установив его объект для моего главного окна setCentralWidget, а с этим что делать? Можно ли вызвать resizeEvent самостоятельно? Наподобие repaint для paintEvent?

Comment: ¿С чего бы он должен срабатывать, когда меняются размеры окна, а не виджета?